# Add scroll to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in which i add rows dynamically and i want to add a vertically scroll to the table when its width get 300 or more. Any tips?

Comment: vertical? width? are you talking about a horizontal scroll, or are you talking about height, or are you trying to do something that i don't understand? edit: well you do mention *rows* so i take it you mean height, hey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap your table in a `<div>` with the `overflow: auto` style, as follows:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```