# How to add scroll to angularjs with dynamically generated elements

Tags: angularjs, html

(Edit:  I have found that the issue is probably not anything related to html and have asked a new hopefully more useful question at 
[Angular routing appears to be preventing scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244932/angular-routing-appears-to-be-preventing-scrolling)
)

I have an angularjs app with a dynamically generated elements and I can't figure out how/where to implement scroll.

I've tried solutions from questions like: [Add scroll to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198070/add-scroll-to-a-table)

But have been unable to get anything to work.  I'm pretty new to frontend so I might be missing something super basic.  Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="menu-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu" role="tab" aria-controls="menu" aria-selected="false">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="scheme-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#scheme" role="tab" aria-controls="scheme" aria-selected="false">Scheme</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">home tab</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="menu-tab">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <ul>
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="addItem" type="button">Add Item to Menu</button>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addItemInput" placeholder="Enter New Item Here" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                <ul id="dynamic-list">
                    <li *ngFor="let i = index; let food of foods">
                        {{i + 1}}:{{food}}
                        <app-sizehtml [number] = i ></app-sizehtml>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="scheme" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="scheme-tab">What?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you get solution for above question?